# Creating an array of values passed using a function in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to get the sum of all the numbers passed to the function but am having some issues.

I want to show the result 17 when array sum is echoed, array('1','4','9','3');

```
result_time(1);
result_time(4);
result_time(9);
result_time(3);

$items = array(); 

function result_time($Num){

    $items[] = $Num;        
}

echo array_sum($items);
```

Can anyone explain what im doing wrong here?

Comment: [read up on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the best way, but you can try adding `global $items;` to your `result_time` function.

```
function result_time($Num)
{
    global $items;
    $items[] = $Num;        
}
```

You can read more infos about variable scope here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

`$items` inside the function and `$items` outside the function are in two different scopes, they're completely different variables. The `$items` inside the function is reset to empty on every call and does also not affect the `$items` outside the function. In essence, your function does nothing. Really properly you should use a class do this:

```
class Result {

    protected $items = array();

    public function add($num) {
        $this->items[] = $num;
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return array_sum($this->items);
    }

}

$r = new Result;
$r->add(1);
...
echo $r->getResult();
```

You may also make the value inside the function accumulate using a `static` variable:

```
function result_time($Num){
    static $items = array();
    $items[] = $Num;
    return $items;
}

result_time(1);
...
$result = result_time(3);

echo array_sum($result);
```

That's not really a good idea though. You may also share the scope of the variables using the `global` keyword, but this is a bad idea and I'm not going to advertise it. Learn about variable scope and structure your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already know all the values you'll want to sum as your code progresses. Why not add them to an array directly?

```
<?php    
$result_times = array();
array_push($result_times, 1);
// some code
array_push($result_times, 4);
// other code
array_push($result_times, 9);

echo array_sum($result_times);
```